# Java code coverage library

Tags: library, java, software-testing, code-coverage

I am setting up code coverage for a multi-module Java application. The application has integration/functional tests which span across modules. For example, `module-service`, `module-dao` and `module-api` would be exercised by a single functional test.

I have the following requirements:

1. **Report transitive code coverage across all three modules:** Tests are present only in `module-service`, but they exercise code in the other two modules as well. I currently use JaCoCo for code coverage because it can calculate this transitive coverage through its run-time instrumentation feature.
2. **Filter out unwanted functions (not classes) from coverage:** A number of compile-time enhancer tools generate synthetic methods and/or code blocks in the compiled code. This skews coverage considerably for smaller classes.

I've tried Cobertura and Emma (which support only[2]) and JaCoCo (which supports only [1]). Is there a good library which supports both of these objectives?

Answer (score 1):

Our (Semantic Designs) [Java Test Coverage Tool](http://www.semanticdesigns.com/Products/TestCoverage/JavaTestCoverage.html) will do this.  It isn't a library; rather it is a set of tools, but I think that is what OP meant anyway.

It operates by instrumenting the *source* code that you designate (on a class source file by class source file basis).  This gives you a lot of control over what gets instrumented.  It also means the test coverage data shown is precise down to line and column; if you have several conditionals in a single line, our test coverage tool will track their statuses separately.

Requirement 1:  If you instrument the 3 modules all at once, you will get a unified test coverage report across all 3 modules.  If  you instrument the 3 modules separately, you can collect/display coverage data for each module separately;  however, the tool can combine test coverage reporting data from different sets of instrumentation, so you can easily construct the report as if you had instrumented all 3 modules at once.

Requirement 2: Automatically generated class files presumably don't have source code that you instrument.  So, no coverage data for those class files is collected.